# Form does not react on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to build a registration-form with javascript. So that the whole registrationprocess is on one site. The site is built with the help of bootstrap and jquery after a tutorial.

I initialize the scripts i have at the beginning of the side with following code:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"> 
   <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/register.js"></script>
</head>
```

The form looks like that:

```
<form class="register-form" method="post" id="register-form">
   <h2 class="form-login-heading">Benutzer registrieren:</h2><hr /> 
   <div id="errorregister"></div>
   <div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Vorname" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname"></div>
   <div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Nachname" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname"></div>
   <div class="form-group"><input placeholder="E-mail" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" /></div>
   <div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Passwort" class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password"></div>
   <div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Passwort bestätigen" class="form-control" id="passwordvali" type="password" name="passwordvali"></div>
   <hr />
   <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="register_button" id="register_button">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>   Registrieren
   </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

The Javascript-File looks like that:

```
    $('document').ready(function() { 
    /* handling form validation */
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
            },
            surname: {
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
            },
            passwordvali: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            firstname:{
              required: "Bitte geben Sie ihren Vornamen ein."
             },
            surname:{
              required: "Bitte geben Sie ihr Nachnamen ein."
             },
            password:{
              required: "Bitte geben Sie ihr Passwort ein."
             },
            passwordvali:{
              required: "Bitte bestätigen Sie ihr Passwort."
             },
            email: "Bitte geben Sie ihre E-Mailadresse ein.",
        },
        submitHandler: submitForm   
    });    
    /* Handling login functionality */
    function submitForm() {     
        var data = $("#register-form").serialize();             
        $.ajax({                
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'registerjava.php',
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function(){ 
                $("#errorregister").fadeOut();
                $("#register_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; übertrage Daten');
            },
            success : function(response){                       
                if(response=="registrationsuccsessful"){                                    
                    $("#errorregister").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
                        $("#errorregister").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Die Registrierung war erfolgreich. Bitte aktivieren Sie ihren Account mit dem Link den wir Ihnen zugeschickt haben.</div>');
                        $("#login_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In');
                } else {                                    
                    $("#errorregister").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
                        $("#errorregister").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response+'</div>');
                        $("#login_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }   
});
```

The problem is, that the Form doesn´t react to the Javascript. Even the validation-error messages aren´t getting displayed.

I build a login-form with the help of the tutorial aswell on the same page, which works, which makes me clueless. Here is the Link to the testfile:

[Link to the testfile](http://www.fabiansquinobal.com/index2.php)

You see in the testfile, when you write in the login-form a not validated e-mailadress a errormessage appears. I don´t know why it doesn´t work in the registrationform.

**EDIT:**

[Here is the link to the working "login javascript-file"](http://www.fabiansquinobal.com/js/login.js)

Here is the code from the working "login-form":

```
<form class="login-form" method="post" id="login-form">
    <h2 class="form-login-heading">Login:</h2><hr /> 
    <div id="errorlogin"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
    <span id="check-e"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="login_button" id="login_button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>   Login
    </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Okay, something magical happened and it works now, but i have no idea why. Maybe my browser had old code in the cache after the changes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't you have to capture the submit event of the form before you can validate it?

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure for bootstrap to work properly jquery has to go before everything else in your code. That's what my console tells me... @JaromandaX

Comment: @JeanPaul98, Bootstrap JS, not CSS.

Comment: jquery is before Bootstrap JS

Comment: I put it at first now, but it did not help.

Comment: You didn't have to put it first, What @TricksfortheWeb said is true, you need something like `$("#register-form").submit(function(e) { /*code here*/ }`

Comment: You have some syntax error on your javascript and you have exactly the same validators in register.js and login.js

Comment: I said he didn't have to do it, I wasn't even looking at the bootstrap.js tbh....I just saw what I wanted to see :/ @JaromandaX

Comment: Im not sure if I am understanding you right with the "capture the submit", but i have nearly the "same" script on the "login-form" and it works. If you click at the link you can see. 

The Javascript of the login-form is on http://www.fabiansquinobal.com/js/login.js

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your code. You need to close the function in your first `fadeIn()` call.

```
if(response=="registrationsuccsessful"){                                    
    $("#errorregister").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
        $("#errorregister").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Die Registrierung war erfolgreich. Bitte aktivieren Sie ihren Account mit dem Link den wir Ihnen zugeschickt haben.</div>');
        $("#login_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In');
}
```

Should be:

```
if(response=="registrationsuccsessful"){                                    
    $("#errorregister").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
        $("#errorregister").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Die Registrierung war erfolgreich. Bitte aktivieren Sie ihren Account mit dem Link den wir Ihnen zugeschickt haben.</div>');
        $("#login_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, i changed it, but it did not help aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You define registration form as class not id 
Use:

```
  $('.register-form').validate()
```

Comment: has the same id as class, so this wouldn't change anything, would it?

Comment: Ohh ok i didnt see your id. Try adding name attribute name="form"

Comment: To your form tag

Comment: I did add name="register-form" - sadly no change.

Comment: role="form" add it